# Attach event to window or document object inside a JQuery call Back function does not work

Tags: jquery, events, window, document

I have a script attached with the  tag that download some file contents using JQuery:

```
$.get('the_file', function(data){

}
```

I need the contents to modify the web layout.

If I try to use the contents inside the onload event:

```
window.addEventListener('load', useTheContents, false);
```

It does not work because the contents are not ready.

So I dispatch an event at the end of the $.get(){} call back function like this:

```
$.get('the_file', function (data) {
    var e = jQuery.Event("MyCustomEvent");
    jQuery("body").trigger(e);
}
```

Then I have this in the main script:

```
$( "body" ).on( "MyCustomEvent", modifyLayout);

function modifyLayout(){

  // The stuff

}
```

And It works fine.

But if I use "window" or "document" instead of "body" it does not work.

I would like to know why.

Comment: Because you should have just called `modifyLayout()` from the callback for the ajax request.

Comment: Ok, I complicated things using events. But still, why it doesn't work when I use "document" or "window".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
But if I use "window" or "document" instead of "body" it does not work.
```

Hope you are not putting window/document inside quotes. body should be inside quotes. Refer below:

```
$("body") -> valid
$(window) -> valid
$(document) -> valid
$("window") -> Invalid
$("document") -> Invalid
```

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Now I wonder where I should read about that. Thanks.